# Inserting date into table cell

Tags: php, date

How do I insert today's date into a table cell? The code that I have doesn't seems to be working and it prints the variable that I store the date with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>

<?php 
    $date = date("Y.m.d"); 
?>

<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>$date</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway I could put the date into the cell?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use php snippet again in html code to print the value in the variable date

`<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to start php tag to use a php variable.

Just replace `<td>$date</td>`

with

`<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>`

Answer (score 2):

I think `<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>` is enough

Answer (score 1):

On the table part:

```
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `$date` variable in `<?php ?>` tags and echo it.

```
<?php echo $date; ?>
```

Hope this helps.